# Why MSBUILD gets error from Rad Studio 10.3 IDE but from command line works?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

In a Rad Studio Rio C++ project, when I compile, I get:

```
MSBUILD : error E1028: unable to open output file '.\Win32\Debug\Unit1\obj': 'no such file or directory'
```

Note that it shows `Unit1\obj`, not `Unit1.obj`.

It works fine if I compile from command line using MSBUILD `MyProject.cbproj`

Also, it works fine if I set on the `Run C++ compiler in separate process`

Also, I have found that the problem is only when I use the Configuration Manager, assigning to the projectt an `.optset` file.  If I unlink this .optset file, then it compiles from the IDE again.

It seems a bug.

Comment: "*It seems a bug*" - then feel free to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: As Remy said, if it is a bug, report it. But ISTM that it may depend on the contents of the *.optset* file too.